# How to page the compile messages of GCC?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am a beginner to Linux console and start write some code in C.

I try to compile code and hope to see messages using command

gcc foo.c -o foo -v | less

But the result text cannot be paged. Any wrong I do? Thanks.

Comment: Presumably the warnings, etc. are on stderr.

Comment: Try `... |& less` instead.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the `emacs` editor and compile *inside* emacs using `M-x compile` (and perhaps a `Makefile`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` pipe command just redirects stdout.  To redirect stderr as well as stdout use `|&`:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo -v |& less
```

Answer (score 2):

The error messages from gcc are going to stderr, and your pipe is only catching stdout.

Assuming that you're using bash, try this to capture stderr as well as stdout:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo -v 2>&1 | less
```

Answer (score 1):

GCC's warnings are printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`. You'd have to redirect that too:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo -v |& less
```